# android how to pop messages when android ip changed?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I need an application that pops up a message every time the network ip has changed. When for example I am moving between wifi-es.

Can someone give me some code examples?

Thx. Appreciate!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can use the tutorial 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/check-rssi-by-monitoring-of.html
which includes broadcast receiver and on receiving such broadcast you can compare previously tored ip and current ip.Hope this will help.